# If loads are perfectly balanced, and line resistances are zero, is ground wire redundant?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, electrical-engineering

Here is my understanding of neutral and ground:

The return current through the neutral wire is the vector sum of three phase power. If loads are perfectly balanced, the vector sum is zero, and the current is therefore also zero.

Households have a connection to this neutral wire, and usually a live connection to one phase. If the wires themselves have zero resistance, this means that the neutral wire is always reliably at the same voltage as 'ground': zero volts.

In this case, is there any need for a physical ground wire at the house? Even for safety reasons? Haven't we guaranteed that neutral and earth are at equal potential?

Comment: Ground is all about human safety, not circuit performance.

Answer (score 0):

Your branch circuit is not 3-phase, even in places where 3-phase is run directly to a household.

Every branch circuit has equal current on both legs.  You can't remove the "neutral"/"grounded conductor".  The grounded conductor is kept near ground, but it absolutely has current running through it.  If the neutral were disconnected, the circuit would not function.

Now you could have a setup where multiple branches are all fed from 3-phase.  If all the branches were perfectly balanced, then the 3-phase would not have to have a return neutral (although it would normally be there for when the phases were imbalanced).  But that is not what is happening on a house circuit.

The branch circuits all have non-zero current when in use.  It is possible that the vector sum of the return current from all the branches is zero when attached to 3-phase power.

> In this case, is there any need for a physical ground wire at the house? Even for safety reasons? Haven't we guaranteed that neutral and earth are at equal potential?

No.  The "neutral" wire is only near ground potential when everything is working.  If the neutral fails, then the appliance can bring the wire up to the same potential as the live wire.  The ground wire (equipment grounding conductor) is a separate safety system.  It provides a *low resistance* path to ground, sufficient for the overcurrent protection (breaker or fuse) to trip if the appliance becomes energized.